# ruby - calculate difference in days

Tags: ruby, date

I am trying to calculate the difference in days (as an integer) between two dates. How do I handle the difference if it is a negative int?

Here is an example of my code.

expiry_date is populated from a JSON response

```
expiry_date #e.g - 2019-04-01

def calculate_date_difference
 (expiry_date - Date.today).to_i
end

if calculate_date_difference.between?(0,90)
 puts "90 days or less"
elsif calculate_date_difference > 90
 puts "more than 90 days"
else 
 puts "past"
end
```

The code works correctly when the expiry_date is in the future, however if the expiry date is in the past then it keeps falling into the wrong condition. For example, the difference in this example is "-9".

I expect it to print "past" but it always prints "90 days of less"

Thanks

Comment: Works for me, how are you creating your `expiry_date`?

Comment: Can you show your exact definition of `expiry_date`? If that's a string you need to `Date.parse` into a `Date`. It's also worth noting you call that method more than once, meaning you need to do the calculations several times. Instead do the calculation once, save it in a variable, then do your comparisons.

Comment: This is where my problem was - I was not using Date.parse on the string. Works as expected now, thanks

Comment: `"2019-04-20" - Date.today #=> NoMethodError (undefined method '-' for "2019-04-20":String)`, so I don't understand how you concluded the code worked correctly for future dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's about smth within your codebase that wasn't provided here, but generally speaking current logic handles it. Updated sample which shows it:

```rb
require 'date'

expiry_date = Date.new(2019,4,1) 

def calculate_date_difference(expiry_date)
  (expiry_date - Date.today).to_i
end

message = if calculate_date_difference(expiry_date).between?(0,90)
  "90 days or less"
elsif calculate_date_difference(expiry_date) > 90
  "more than 90 days"
else 
  "past"
end

message == "past" # true
```